# Advantage of math mode only for numbers

Tags: math-mode, text-mode, number

I wonder whether it makes a difference to write numbers, e.g., `3.1416` in *math mode* `$3.1416$` or it is exactly the same as in *text mode*.
I have many numbers in my document, especially decimal numbers, and I have to decide if I put them in math mode (more cumbersome) or not.

I have made a mini test and see no difference

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

%Text mode
This is 3.1416 (\verb|3.1416|)

%Math mode
This is $3.1416$ (\verb|$3.1416$|)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Irrespectively of whether there is a difference in your MWE. there are tools like `\everymath` that selectively apply stuff to math mode expressions. So, unless you are sure that you will never use one of those (which are often implicit in packages) it is arguably cleaner to add the `$` signs.

Comment: Have you seen the postings [Numbers outside Math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38820/5001) and [When to use math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37168/5001)?

Comment: Try your example with -3.1416.

Comment: @IanThompson There we go, yes I see the minus sign is a first advantage of using math mode.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `\everymath` is a point for using `$`, certainly, however, in my opinion, "clearness" is not really achieved adding more symbols to the source code.

Comment: Do you know the book “Discrete Mathematics” by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik? *That* very Knuth! In the book, numbers (when considered in their mathematical sense) are typeset in the Euler font: math mode *is* definitely needed.

Comment: @Mico I think the first post you suggested, answers quite thoroughly my question. Sorry, I did not find it: you can mark as dupplicate. :-\

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I looked up the book. The right name is "Concrete Mathematics". ;)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus I always mix it up, sorry.

Comment: Clearness and cleanliness may not be the same. So, yes, the `$` signs make the source code a bit harder to read (maybe) but you have a structured document. Anyway, the `$` seems to lose value these days, so your question is very timely. ;-)